# Blazor Individual Accounts pages throwing NullReferenceException even after adding global interactivity?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am on .NET 8.0 and have a Blazor Web App with Individual Accounts (ASP.NET Identity), and page interactivity set to server *globally*. For the default login page, I am trying to add some interactivity with onclick events however that does not work in the static page as is.

I am aware that the ongoing issue of manually adding `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to the top caused the login page to throw NullReferenceException. On all the forums that I visited, the workaround included adding `@rendermode="RenderModeForPage"` to  and  tags, with the additional:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}
```

code in the App.razor file. This is also included in the template generated for Blazor WebApp in Visual Studio anyways. However, it seems like this addition to App.razor ONLY works on pages that are NOT in the Account directory. The interactive rendering seems to work for the home page correctly, without any exceptions, but I need to add @rendermode InteractiveServer to the Login page to enable interactive rendering, which ends up throwing the exception. What am I doing wrong here? I have searched everywhere and no one seems to have brought up this issue.

**Edit**: To clarify, I am currently using a template generated from Visual Studio with the options in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyHva.png). The code block above was already there in Components/App.razor page. I then tried to check if I was able to rewrite a simple counter, using a button, in one of the pages in Components/Account/ pages (let's say the Login.razor page). This did not work because apparently the Login page is not interactive. After I tried adding the line `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to the top, the lines `if (HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))` and `<StatusMessage Message="@errorMessage" />` threw a NullReferenceException. Everything worked fine however, after I commented these two lines out. This led me to conclude that it was the template at fault which did not actually apply global interactivity to the Account pages, despite the code block above.

Comment: The accounts pages are statically rendered pages.  You can't just make them interactive by adding `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to them.  You need to redesign them.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `HttpContext` in the way you are.  If you need to check for pre=rendering you should be using `IHttpContextAccessor`.  If the forum posts are suggesting using `HttpContext`, then I wouldn't trust any other information either.  See https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.RenderState for how to use `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: See this commentary - https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-introducing-the-identity-api-endpoints/

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis My bad, it seems like I wasn't clear: all the code that I'm using was generated from the template itself, generated from Visual Studio. I did not add anything to the already generated pages. except for wanting to add interactivity to a switch from MudBlazor and that doesn't seem to work without me adding `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to the login page. This makes `HttpContext` throw the NullReferenceException.

Comment: The generated pages are all static server side rendered pages.  You can't just add *InteractiveServer* to make them Blazor pages.  They use `HttpContext`, but you shouldn't within a Blazor App. You get the error because there's no such thing as a  `HttpContext` in the Blazor Server context.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Ahhh I see. It seems like I have misunderstood how page rendering and interactivity in Blazor works. Will have to do more research. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: See this commentary https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md  and this very recent answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77891687/handle-static-blazor-form-component-on-mvc-page/77892068#77892068