# Handle Static Blazor Form Component on MVC Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, blazor, blazor-server-side

In theory posting Blazor forms using the Static render mode should work.
However, it's not handled by Blazor, it's handled as an MVC form, posting to `/`.

*As per request of the customer, I use the Static render mode.*

What am I missing?

1. Interactivity?
2. Blazor's `<Router />` ?
3. Blazor's script tag? `<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>`

Assumptions:

- Interactivity shouldn't be required.
- Both 2 & 3 would make sense but than we're headed into full SPA mode whilst the customer prefers gradual evolution towards that.

It's possible to render Blazor components on your MVC pages, in multiple ways:

1. Example using `RenderComponentAsync`:

```cs
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<SubscribeToNewsletterForm>(RenderMode.Static, new
    {
        BtnLabel = "Subscribe"
    }))
```

2. Example using :

```cs
    <component type="@(typeof(SubscribeToNewsletterForm))" render-mode="Static" />
```

I have tried:

- both approaches but Blazor is not handling the form post.
- adding `<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>` including the `BlazorFrameworkFiles` to no avail.

Finally, I created a full Blazor SPA using the static render mode and I moved the MVC to run on different routes.

The Blazor SPA handles the form correctly so my assumption is that the Blazor `<Router />` was needed to intervene form posting and navigation.

Is my assumption correct?
If so, using Blazor components on an MVC page is limited to rendering only?

The Blazor component with form:

```cs
<EditForm Model="@SubscriptionModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleSubscriptionForm" FormName="SubscriptionModel">
    <FluentValidationValidator/>

    <div class="input-group">
        <InputText type="email" class="form-control email-input" required
                   placeholder="Enter your email" aria-label="Enter your email" @bind-Value="SubscriptionModel.Email"/>

        <button class="btn btn-primary subscribe-button" type="submit">@BtnLabel</button>
    </div>

    <ValidationSummary/>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? BtnLabel { get; set; } = "Join";

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public SubscribeToNewsletterRequest? SubscriptionModel { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SubscriptionModel ??= new SubscribeToNewsletterRequest();
    }

    private async Task HandleSubscriptionForm()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling subscription form...");
        ...
    }

    public record SubscribeToNewsletterRequest
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex topic, that I'll try and summarise here.

You need to be quite careful talking about server side rendering with Blazor Server because a component may be rendered in one of two places.

1. Static Server Side Rendered [SSSR] is where the component is rendered within the `HttpRequest` context.  Everything except Singleton services are created and destroyed within the context.  This is classic old style MVC, Razor and ASP.
2. Active Server Side Rendered [ASSR] is where an SPA session on the browser is rendered in a Hub Session context in the Blazor hub.

As the code you've provided isn't a working MRE [minimal Reproducible Example], I'll use the *Starship* example code from the MS Documentation. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

With the Routes component set as follows in `App`:

```cs
    <Routes />
```

The page below will be rendered ASSR in the *HttpRequest Context*.

```cs
@page "/starship"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@inject ILogger<Starship> Logger

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@Submit" FormName="Starship">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <label>
        Identifier:
        <InputText @bind-Value="Model!.Id" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public Starship? Model { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => Model ??= new();

    private void Submit()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Id = {Id}", Model?.Id);
    }

    public class Starship
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Id is too long.")]
        public string? Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The form will post the page back to the server and it will be processed by the `Starship` form.  Enter more than 10 letters into the Id and tab out of the input and nothing happens.  There's no interactivity, because there's none defined.  Validation will only take place when you post the form back to the server.

Try and make say `InputText` interactive to try and show the validation message.  You will get an error. `InputText` relies on cascaded parameters from `EditForm` that aren't there when `EditForm` is statically rendered.  They existed in the *HttpRequest Context* where `EditForm` was rendered.  But `InputText` exists in the *Hub Session Context*.

Add Interactivity to the whole form and now you get the interactive stuff in the page.  Enter too many letters and tab away triggers in form validation and you get an immediate validation message.

```cs
@page "/starship"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@inject ILogger<Starship> Logger
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@Submit" FormName="Starship">
```

In this scenario the router is still running in SSSR mode so every page is posted back to the server, initially statically rendered and then rendered according to the page/component's render setting.

If you set:

```cs
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

Then you are setting it globally.  This is the same as the old *Blazor Server* mode.  The router is not rendered within the SPA and there's no posting back to the server.

*Personal Comment*

If this is a migration from an existing server side rendered application then running in mixed mode to do an incremental migration is fine.  If this is a new application, there's no point. Extra complexity = significantly higher cost for what?

Comment: Thanks for the response. All I'm trying to understand is whether my assumption is correct that without the Blazor Router and framework files, I can only render Blazor components on an MVC page, not handle forms with Blazor. Thus, an MVC app and Blazor app can run alongside eachother, live in the same project but not really intergrate seamlessly.
So, having an MVC page render a Blazor EditForm and expect Blazor to handle that form likely does more harm than good due to their routers & nature working against eachother, right?

Comment: Yes, but you can do Blazor forms stuff by setting interactivity on the form page as I've done in the example.  The router [and layout] is still running statically and will route between SSSR and ASSR pages in the `@body` parameter of the layout.  What you don't get are the cascading parameters from `Routes` and the layout.  You can create mechanisms for MVC and Blazor app pages to communicate and share state, but those are not build in, and as I've said, add a serious amount of complexity.

Comment: Interesting, but that implies adding Routes.razor, App.razor, blazor.web.js, MainLayout.razor, ... At this stage you're running a full SPA alongside your MVC? Or do you mean adding <Routes /> and blazor.web.js to each MVC page or on the _Layout.cshtml? To my knowledge you can't just add <Routes /> on a .cshtml, maybe with the tag helper. To put it simply, the goal would be to e.g. have an existing MVC filled with jQuery, to replace the jQuery with Blazor and later replace all the Views with Blazor. We're looking for the in-between stages MVC to SPA. If any, since it's an SPA framework.

Comment: Yes to the first.